# ng-Show doesn't work with directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which is shown (or should to) if "isEmpty" variable is true

```
// index.html
<div empty-notes-screen coleccion="Notes" ng-show="isEmpty"></div>

// directive.js
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('emptyNotesScreen', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/notes/emptynotesscreen.html', 
        replace: true,
        scope : {
            coleccion : '='
        },
        link : function (scope, elm,attrs){
            scope.$watchCollection('coleccion', function(newValue) {
                if(newValue.length>0){
                    scope.isEmpty = false;            
                }
                else{
                    scope.isEmpty = true;                   
                }
                console.log('isEmpty: ',scope.isEmpty);
                console.log(' coleccion has changed');
            });
        }
    };
  });


// views/notes/emptynotesscreen.html
<div class="white-text">
    <div  class="center grey darken-2" style="padding: 45px;">
        <img width="180px" src="images/ignotize-white.png">
        <h4>There's no notes yet!</h4>
        <p>Please, add a note at least to see it here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I have a controller that looks like this:

```
// scripts/index.js
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('IndexNoteCtrl', function ($scope, NoteResource) {

    $scope.Notes = NoteResource.query();

  });
```

The result is, scope.isEmpty changes accordingly but in the HTML, the isEmpty never changes!! So that HTML never show or hide.
I don't know why or where I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Probably due to ```replace: true```

Comment: Are you debugging a controller or a directive? If a directive - did you try to put manually in your controller '$scope.isEmpty = true;' to see what's rendered by directive?

Comment: Your `isEmpty` never appeared in the parent scope, where `ngShow` evaluated.

Comment: @Grievoushead , I've removed "replace:true" and It stil doesn't work.

Comment: @vp_arth , you're right, ng-show is evaluted by his parent controller (outsided scope) .

Comment: @shershen and also I've tried to put "isEmpty" in the controller without any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the variable `isEmpty` on the scope of the directive.

But you are trying to use this variable outside of the directive, where it has no value.  You can fix this problem in at least two ways:

1) Move the `ng-show` so that it inside the template for the directive: `<div class="white-text" ng-show="isEmpty">...</div>`

2) Get rid of the watcher, and `isEmpty` and everything related to it. Then in your index.html where you use the directive use ng-show:  `ng-show="Notes.length >0"`